# Intellij plugin: Intention for xml file that replace an attribute with two custom attribute with different prefix with same value

Tags: java, xml, intellij-plugin

On a plugin I want to do the following  action for an intention in XML file.

Intention appear when you are on an xml attribute (cursor on text)

When intention is invoked I want to add two attribute to label tag like below:

what's the code that replace  text="hello" with i:text="hello" a:text="hello"

I tried the code below:

```
import com.intellij.codeInsight.FileModificationService;
import com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.PsiElementBaseIntentionAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.application.Result;
import com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Editor;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElement;
import com.intellij.psi.XmlElementFactory;
import com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlAttribute;
import com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlAttributeValue;
import com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlTag;
import com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlToken;
import com.intellij.util.IncorrectOperationException;
import org.igu.plugins.nativescript.NsBundle;
import org.igu.plugins.nativescript.NsFacade;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

/**
 */
public class PlatformSpecificPropertyValue extends PsiElementBaseIntentionAction {

    public PlatformSpecificPropertyValue() {
        setText(NsBundle.message("intention.declare.platform.specific.property.value"));
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(@NotNull Project project, Editor editor, @NotNull PsiElement psiElement) throws IncorrectOperationException {
        if (psiElement instanceof XmlToken) {
            XmlToken xmlToken = (XmlToken) psiElement;
            final PsiElement parent = xmlToken.getParent();
            if (parent instanceof XmlAttribute) {
                XmlAttribute xmlAttribute = (XmlAttribute) parent;
                String localName = xmlAttribute.getLocalName();
                String value = xmlAttribute.getValue();
                final XmlTag tag = xmlAttribute.getParent();
                final XmlAttribute iAttribute = XmlElementFactory.getInstance(project).createAttribute("i:"+localName, value, tag);
                final XmlAttribute aAttribute = XmlElementFactory.getInstance(project).createAttribute("a:"+localName, value, tag);
                if (!FileModificationService.getInstance().prepareFileForWrite(xmlAttribute.getContainingFile())) {
                    return;
                }

                new WriteCommandAction(project, tag.getContainingFile()) {
                    @Override
                    protected void run(@NotNull Result result) throws Throwable {
                        tag.addAfter(xmlAttribute, iAttribute);
                        tag.addBefore(xmlAttribute, aAttribute);
                        xmlAttribute.delete();
                    }
                }.execute();


            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailable(@NotNull Project project, Editor editor, @NotNull PsiElement psiElement) {
        return psiElement instanceof XmlToken;
    }

    @Nls
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getFamilyName() {
        return getText();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the two arguments of `addAfter()` and `addBefore()`:

```
/**
 * Adds a child to this PSI element, after the specified anchor element.
 *
 * @param element the child element to add.
 * @param anchor  the anchor after which the child element is inserted (must be a child of this PSI element)
 * @return the element which was actually added (either <code>element</code> or its copy).
 * @throws IncorrectOperationException if the modification is not supported or not possible for some reason.
 */
PsiElement addAfter(@NotNull PsiElement element, @Nullable PsiElement anchor) throws IncorrectOperationException;
```

The correct code should be:

```
tag.addAfter(iAttribute, xmlAttribute);
tag.addBefore(aAttribute, xmlAttribute);
xmlAttribute.delete();
```